# Применить код к последним строкам для каждой строки

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Есть таблица формата

| Id | date | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01 | 5 |
| 1 | 01.02 | 15 |
| 1 | 01.03 | 20 |
| 1 | 01.04 | 20 |
| 1 | 01.05 | 40 |

и есть код

```
with cte_1 as (
select *,  ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by balance) as  rank
from table
)

SELECT id,
    1 - 2 * sum((cast(balance as float) * (rank - 1) + balance / 2)) / count(*) / sum(balance) AS gini
FROM cte_1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Как написать запрос, чтобы расчеты применялись для снимка в 4 строки для каждой строки.
Вот так:
[image: Как должно считать]

Для даты 01.04 берутся строки с датами 01.01 - 01.04, для 01.05 берутся строки 01.02-01.05 и т.п.